# How to reset css in IE11 to be compatible with IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Note: Before posting this question, have gone through MSDN and also stackoverflow existing questions.
Working on a website; where users are migrating to IE11 from IE8.  Facing rendering issues and I have observed if I set IE11 Document mode emulated to IE8 the page displays with almost like IE8.  compared the css computed in IE8 and IE11, IE11 computes lot of css that I am trying to remove;  such that it could solve the rendering issues.  Attaching images in IE11 Computed CSS and IE8.  Want to reset IE11 default Computed CSS with IE8.  How can I do that? 
I have tried using meta tag  it didn't work, also I do not want the website to fallback to older version rending;  eventually the webpage should continue working in newer version IE11.
IE11 & IE8 - css Computed
[image]
[image]

Comment: Use `<!doctype html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`, a css reset/normalize file as base before you start creating you styling and use wellformed html. If you that will not encounter not many problems since IE 8. Especially 10 and 11 behave like normal modern browsers if you don't try to treat them as IE. Especially `Want to reset IE11 default Computed CSS with IE8`  sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!  I started rewriting most of the css.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use browser detection and based on that render different CSS files.
something like:

```
<!--[if IE lt 9]><link href="/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!    [endif]-->
<!--[if IE eq 11]><link href="/ie11.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Happy that it was helpful.